# Deduce the following argument. Propositional logic

Tags: logic

I am not quite sure about my process for asserting the following statement:

$$A \rightarrow B\vee C (1)\\
B \rightarrow \neg A (2) \\
D \rightarrow\neg C (3) \\
-----------\\
\neg (A \wedge D) \ this \ is \ the \ conclusion$$

This is my solution:

I first take (1). For it to be true, either A is false (and we cannot say anything about $B \vee C$), or A is true and $B \vee C$ is also true. **I supposed** A is true.

Taking (2), B should be false for it hold (if B were to be true, then $\neg A$ would also be true, and then we would get a contradiction).

Since i supposed A was true and (1) holds, modus ponens implies $B \vee C$ is true. Since B es false, it leaves us with C being true.

Finally for (3) to hold, D should be false. If D were to be true, then $\neg C$ would also be true and we would have a contradiction i.e., $(C \wedge \neg C)$.

This being said, it is not possible for A and D to be true at the same time, meaning $\neg (A\wedge D)$

My questions relies in the bold text highlighted. Is it correct to assume a truth value for A?

Remark: The problem said "Give a deduction for the following statement...". Is my solution a deduction?

Thank you.

Comment: Proof it by contradiction, assuming $A \land D$ as true.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if supposing A is true is an incorrect step?

Comment: @Max $A$ and $D$ are *derivable* under the assumption of $A\wedge D$ . Hence, by your proof by cases above, you may derive a contradiction under the assumption of $(A\wedge D)$.  This allows you to *deduce* $\neg(A\wedge D)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is not wrong.

However, if you can derive a contradiction *under the assumption* of $A\wedge D$, then you may deduce that $\neg(A\wedge D)$ is derivable.

So do that .

---

> Take $A\to (B\vee C)$, $B\to\neg A$, and $D\to\neg C$ as premises.
>
> Suppose $A\wedge D$ holds.  (From this we may derive $A$ and $D$.)  Given $D$ and the third premise we can derive $\neg C$.  Given $A$ and the first premise we may derive $B\vee C$.  *If* $B$ is the case, and using the second premise, *then* we can derive $\neg A$, a contradiction, *or else if* $C$ is the case, *then* we have a contradiction (since $\neg C$ has been derived).  So, in either case, a contradiction may be derived under the supposition.
>
> We therefore deduce that $\neg(A\wedge D)$ is derivable from these premises.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Graham! I am new to math stack exchange and its pleasing to get feedback from enthusiasts like you.